# make - mysterious errors from nonexistent files

Tags: makefile, mingw

I recently tried to modify my makefile so that it will correctly rebuild files when a header is modified. However, I can't get it to work - it instead produces mysterious error messages about nonexistent files.

My current makefile is as follows

```
HEADER_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.h) $(wildcard src/*/*.h)
CPP_FILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) $(wildcard src/*/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst src/%.cpp,obj/%.o,$(CPP_FILES))
LD_FLAGS :=
CC_FLAGS := -Wall -fwrapv -std=c++0x -DNOMINMAX -DFLOAT_CONV -DNODEBUGLOGGING
# CC_FLAGS := -Wall -fwrapv -std=c++0x -DNOMINMAX -DFLOAT_CONV -DMUSIC

INC = src Box2D SDL-1.2.15/include SDL-1.2.15/include/SDL C:/Boost/boost_1_55_0
CC_FLAGS += $(foreach d, $(INC), -I$d)

LINK_PATHS = SDL-1.2.15/lib C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib Box2D\Build\Box2D
LINK = mingw32 SDLmain SDL_mixer SDL_image SDL_ttf SDL Box2d boost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_55 boost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-d-1_55
LD_FLAGS += $(foreach d, $(LINK_PATHS), -L$d)
LD_FLAGS += $(foreach d, $(LINK), -l$d)

EXE_NAME := Pickory/Pickory.exe

depend: .depend

.depend: $(HEADER_FILES) $(CPP_FILES)
    g++ $(CC_FLAGS) -MM $^>>./.depend;

include .depend

# main.exe: $(OBJ_FILES)
$(EXE_NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
    g++  -o $@ $^ $(LD_FLAGS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    -mkdir $(subst /,\,$(dir $@))
    g++ $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

run: $(EXE_NAME)
    (cd Pickory && $(notdir $(EXE_NAME)))
.PHONY: run
```

However, the depend target is producing error messages

```
g++: error: src/CommonEntities/defaltgun.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: error: src/TutorialTunnel/roomdef_tt.cpp;: No such file or directory
makefile:21: recipe for target '.depend' failed
mingw32-make: *** [.depend] Error 1
```

This is rather strange, since there is no such "defaltgun" file, and in fact, "defaltgun" appears nowhere in the entire source code. What could be going on? And how can I fix my makefile?

P.S. The `.depend` file is empty. So presumably gcc isn't properly generating dependencies either.

Comment: What did you modify? And what do you get if you put `$(info $(CPP_FILES))` above the `depend` rule?

Comment: I added the .depend rule. And `$(info $(CPP_FILES))` prints out a list of 146 files, but defaltgun is nowhere among them, which isn't surprising since there's no such file.

Comment: I suggest you work toward a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/); eliminate all rules except the one for `.depend`, remove the "include depend" line, then start removing source files (e.g. by copying the entire tree then deleting files, or just temporarily moving directories down out of sight of the `wildcard` calls). Keep going until the error disappears, and if you still can't see the bug, post something we can reproduce.

Comment: I ended up rewriting the makefile to use a completely different method, so it's not that big a deal. But I'm still curious how gcc managed to pull those filenames out of thin air.